# Using artifact repository for storing full releases?

Tags: deployment, build, artifactory, artifact

I've been looking into artifact repositories for something that our release team can use for storing outputs of full builds from multiple projects. From what I've read, artifact repositories are mostly used for storing library files required for a build. My assumption is that their intended use is to ensure developers and build servers are using the exact same binary dependencies during build process.

Few questions:

- Is it possible to store the build output of entire projects into an artifact repository (A full release), a place to store artifacts ready for deployment?
- Is this common practice?
- Is it possible to have analytics of what was changed since the last build? Ex: can I see which artifacts have changed since the last release?

Answer (score 2):

So, the short answer to your questions are: yes, yes, and mostly yes.

While it is true that Binary Managers such as [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Welcome+to+Artifactory) are used for dependency management they are also used to host entire builds. 
In Artifactory this can be easily achieved through the [Build Integration features](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration). If you are not using any CI server such as [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) (for example) you can use the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/Welcome+to+JFrog+CLI) to upload your builds and their corresponding [Build Info](https://github.com/JFrogDev/build-info).

In addition, with regards to analytics, not exactly as such, but in Artifactory you have the option to perform [Build Diff](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration#BuildIntegration-BuildDiff) and see the changes between builds.

Hope I helped,

Eran

p.s. I work for JFrog

Comment: Thanks for the response, it's always neat getting responses from the engineers who actually work on these tools.

Comment: How are these build diffs made? Is it a product from the CI integration or can the metadata for a build be manually made to encapsulate multiple projects? Where I work 'builds' are another term for sprint. Each sprint multiple teams compiles/deploys their binaries/artifacts and we integrate them to their respective servers/projects. Can we have multiple artifacts from multiple projects going to and from multiple locations but be grouped as one build?

Answer (score 1):

Using Sonatype Nexus woks for what you need, you are able to deploy not just Java artifacts (example: .ear, .jar, .war files) you are able to deploy any kind of binaries, we are using it for storing reports for Orace BI Publisher, or .exe binaries.

**Is it possible to store the build output of entire projects into an artifact repository (A full release), a place to store artifacts ready for deployment?**
Yes, as I said before, you can store any kind of binaries you want.

**Is this common practice?**
I don't know if it is a common practice, but in my case It helped us to keep an order. Just evaluate if it works for you.

**Is it possible to have analytics of what was changed since the last build? Ex: can I see which artifacts have changed since the last release?**

Sonatype Nexus handle a version for each artifact (or binary) so you are able to store all the "history" from your deployments, also it is able to handle security policy for example you could not deploy the same binary twice with the same version it forces you deploy a new version in this way you can verify when an artifact has changed, the date and who uploaded the artifact.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Our current problem is we have a massive system that is currently (to some extent) manually deployed. This is a by-product of having many projects with many differing technologies. We need a way to have a 'what's changed' list for our integration team (our current system is very custom) before we take the plunge into devops. Is there a way to check what has changed since an iteration period?

Comment: About "What has changed?" you mean in the code , right? If that is the point verify that in the binary it isn't a good idea, I have configured jenkins using a pipeline that produces a binary and then deploy it in Nexus. How it works? You do checkout from SVN (or git) and in the pipeline you can see actually the commit comments and what files has changed, this then will be deployed in Nexus as a Binary (compiled code), so somehow you can see what has changed if you are using some CI (as Jenkins) in your organization

Comment: I mean what has changed in the artifact repository after a sprint period. Right now we have a manual process for integration that we need to keep until we're able for full automated build-deployment-integration. Right now we have about 20 projects with differing technologies that all live under the same release cycle. To simplify things for our integration team we need a list to see what was changed since the last sprint to satisfy our requirements while we work up to DevOps.